# I want to initialize the struct using this RegisterSymbol() function but got this error: expected expression before '{' token?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, microcontroller, microchip, mplab

```
typedef void (*func_get)() ;     //  function pointer

void RegisterSymbol(Symbol *S1)
{
    symbolDic[dicIndex].SymbolId  = S1->SymbolId ;
    symbolDic[dicIndex].get =  S1->get ;
}   

void SymbolInit()                //array initilizer
{
    RegisterSymbol(0x0A ,Get_temp());
    RegisterSymbol({10, &getTempRawAdc()});
}

typedef struct              //structure
{
    uint32_t  SymbolId; 
    func_get get;
} Symbol;
```

Please help me to configure the error as I try to assign value to the element of structure but could not succeed

Comment: Have you tried moving the `typedef struct` definition up above where its members are referred? To just below the first `typedef`.

Comment: First format your code correctly. It cannot be read

Comment: Also the first call to `RegisterSymbol` is passing 2 arguments where 1 is expected.

Comment: Note that `dicIndex` is not incremented between the two calls, so the second call would overwrite the array elements set by the first call. But it is unclear anyway why you define a `struct` and then later split the members across different arrays. The `struct` does not seem to be used for anything. Why not just pass two arguments to the function?

Answer (score 0):

Given a function declared as yours is:

> ```
> void RegisterSymbol(Symbol *S1)
> ```

The argument must be a pointer to a `Symbol` structure.  There is a variety of ways to provide that.  Here is a particularly simple alternative:

```
void f() {
    // Declare s as a Symbol, with initializer:
    Symbol s = { 0x0A, Get_temp };  // pointer to Get_temp, not the result of calling it
    // Pass the address of s
    RegisterSymbol(&s);
}
```

Or, provided that your compiler conforms to at least C99, among your other options would be to pass the address of a compound literal:

```
void f() {
    // Pass the address of s
    RegisterSymbol(&(Symbol){ 0x0A, Get_temp });
}
```

It is important at this point to observe that the lifetime of the object represented by that compound literal ends when execution of the innermost containing block (the body of `f()`) completes, but that doesn't matter because your `RegisterSymbol()` method does not retain a copy of the passed pointer, and the literal's members are not encumbered the same way.

But since indeed the registration function *doesn't* retain the passed pointer, you could consider having it instead receive a structure by value:

```
void RegisterSymbol(Symbol S1) {
    symbolDic[dicIndex].SymbolId  = S1.SymbolId ;
    symbolDic[dicIndex].get =  S1.get ;
}

void f() {
    // Pass a copy of a Symbol
    RegisterSymbol((Symbol){10, Get_temp});
}
```

or receive the structure members directly:

```
void RegisterSymbol(uint32_t SymbolId, func_get get) {
    symbolDic[dicIndex].SymbolId  = SymbolId ;
    symbolDic[dicIndex].get =  get ;
}

void f() {
    // Pass the components of a symbol
    RegisterSymbol(10, Get_temp};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef void (*func_get)() ;     //  function pointer

void RegisterSymbol(Symbol *S1)
{
    symbolDic[dicIndex].SymbolId  = S1->SymbolId ;
    symbolDic[dicIndex].get =  S1->get ;
}
```

When the compiler sees **Symbol*** the type **Symbol** is not yet defined...
Put your type definitions at the top of the file or at a header file

Compare with this code

```
typedef void (*func_get)();     //  function pointer

void Get_temp();
void getTempRawAdc();

typedef struct              //structure
{
    uint32_t    SymbolId;
    func_get    get;

}   Symbol;

void RegisterSymbol(Symbol* S1, Symbol symbolDic[])
{
    static unsigned int dicIndex = 0;
    symbolDic[dicIndex].SymbolId = S1->SymbolId;
    symbolDic[dicIndex].get = S1->get;
    dicIndex += 1;
    return;
};

void SymbolInit(Symbol dic[])
{
    Symbol local;
    local.SymbolId = 0x0A;
    local.get = Get_temp;
    RegisterSymbol(&local, dic);
    local.SymbolId = 0x0A;
    local.get = Get_temp;
    RegisterSymbol(&local, dic);
    return;
};

void Get_temp(){};
void getTempRawAdc(){};
```

This is just something that compiles and builds an array of Symbols for you to compare and fit to your needs